# Validar diferença de 5 pontos para mais ou menos

Tags: javascript

Preciso fazer uma validação se um valor tem uma diferença de até 5, tanto para positivo quando para negativo. Gostaria de saber se existe alguma função do JavaScript que me auxilie nisso, sem ter que fazer o seguinte `if` gigante:

```js
let scoreboard_local_team = 22;
let scoreboard_visiting_team = 26;
let points = 0;

if (
  scoreboard_local_team + 1 === scoreboard_visiting_team ||
  scoreboard_local_team + 2 === scoreboard_visiting_team ||
  scoreboard_local_team + 3 === scoreboard_visiting_team ||
  scoreboard_local_team + 4 === scoreboard_visiting_team ||
  scoreboard_local_team - 1 === scoreboard_visiting_team ||
  scoreboard_local_team - 2 === scoreboard_visiting_team ||
  scoreboard_local_team - 3 === scoreboard_visiting_team ||
  scoreboard_local_team - 4 === scoreboard_visiting_team
  ) {
  points += 30;
}

console.log(points)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você pode calcular a diferença e usar [`Math.abs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs) para obter o valor absoluto desta (ou seja, o valor sem sinal):

```js
let scoreboard_local_team = 22;
let scoreboard_visiting_team = 26;
let points = 0;
// se a diferença é menor que 5
if (Math.abs(scoreboard_local_team - scoreboard_visiting_team) < 5) {
  points += 30;
}

console.log(points)
```

---

Não ficou muito claro se a diferença entre os valores pode ser zero, pois não tem essa condição no seu `if`. O código acima assume que pode, mas caso não possa, basta mudar para:

```js
let scoreboard_local_team = 22;
let scoreboard_visiting_team = 26;
let points = 0;
let diff = Math.abs(scoreboard_local_team - scoreboard_visiting_team);
if (0 < diff && diff < 5) {
  points += 30;
}

console.log(points)
```

Answer (score 5):

Imagino que tem até um erro nesta lógica e o que quer seria estabelecer se está dentro de uma faixa, e isto é feito sempre comparando a variável desejada com o menor valor possível e o maior valor possível. Se estiver dentro da faixa é verdadeiro, assim:

```
if (scoreboard_visiting_team > scoreboard_local_team - 4 && scoreboard_visiting_team <scoreboard_local_team + 4)
```

Pode ser que realmente não deve ser verdadeiro se for exatamente igual ao valor da variável, então precisaria mudar um detalhe e fazer uma exceção, mas eu duvido que isto seria coreto, o código abaixo faz igual ao seu código, que eu acho estar errado:

```
if (scoreboard_visiting_team > scoreboard_local_team - 4 && scoreboard_visiting_team <scoreboard_local_team + 4 && scoreboard_visiting_team != scoreboard_local_team)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/ValidationValue.js).